# How to Dynamically Create a Submit Button with an "onclick" Event Attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I coded the following in order to produce a dynamic submit button that will send email when clicked, but it;s not working.

```
    function createbuttomdyanmic()
    {

        var button = document.createElement('input');
        button.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
        button.setAttribute('ID', 'btnSendMail');
        button.setAttribute('value', 'Send Mail');
        button.setAttribute('onclick', 'btnSendMail_Click');
        document.body.appendChild(button);
        button.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-primary");
        $('#button').addClass('myClass');

    }
```

Also, I need to add this style, but it is also not appearing.

```
 margin-left:1407px;
    width:98px;
```

Comment: Can't you create a button server side and attach event in there? What server side language you are using?

Comment: Aren't you adding the `myClass` class to the wrong element? During declaration, you give the id `btnSendMail` to the button, then you're adding the last class on `#button`.

Comment: You'll need to create a `form` element too, to be able to submit anything to the server. For us to be able to help out we need a _working_ code snippet, not only code fragments

Answer (score 2):

There are some points that needs to be fixed in your code:

- We don't set event handlers with `setAttribute()` method.

You can use **[addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)** like this:

```
button.addEventListener('click', btnSendMail_Click);
```

Or `onclick` like this:

```
button.onclick = function(){ 
   btnSendMail_Click()
};
```

- You can use  [**.classList**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to add class to a given element instead of using `setAttribute("class")`.

Like this:

```
button.classList.Add("btn", "btn-primary");
```

- And if your `button` doesn't belong to any `form` you will just need to use 
  `type="button"`, otherwise just put it inside a `form` element because a `submit` button is generally iused to submit a form.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the code ran pretty well -- just a few corrections and suggestions, as follows:

Having a submit button implies that it should be an element of a form, although you may position it outside the form with HTML5 using the "form" attribute.

This next bit of code seems extraneous, given that it is the only line of jQuery and it refers to an element with an id of "button" and yet the submit button has an id of "btnSendMail" so I commented it out:

```
//$('#button').addClass('myClass');
```

The name of the function that creates the dynamic submit button appears to have a typo.  If you call that function in your code without the typo, then the function won't execute.  So until the name is clear, I deleted the name entirely turning it into an anonymous function.

There is nothing wrong in using setAttribute() to set the value of the onclick event attribute.  Another way is to use addEventListener(); both run fine in Google Chrome except that setAttribute() is the faster of the two; see [here](https://jsperf.com/onclick-vs-setattribute/2).  While submit buttons are typically used to submit forms, there is some flexibility as long as one provides a "formaction" attribute if you prefer to redirect the browser to a url, even a javascript url works!

Lastly, you provided CSS code without indicating what class it should pertain to, so I took the liberty  of turning it into styling for the .btn class.  I also changed the code so the button wasn't nearly hidden from view with my old-fashioned monitor. I added some color too to make the button stand out for testing.

```js
function btnSendMail_Click() {
  console.log('Button clicked; email sent');
}

(function() {

  var button = document.createElement('input');
  button.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
  button.setAttribute('ID', 'btnSendMail');
  button.setAttribute('value', 'Send Mail');
  button.setAttribute('onclick', 'btnSendMail_Click()');
  button.setAttribute('form', 'myform');
  document.body.appendChild(button);
  button.setAttribute("class", "btn btn-primary");
  button.setAttribute("formaction", "javascript: console.log('bye');")
  //$('#button').addClass('myClass');

}());
```

```css
.btn {
  margin-left: 207px;
  width: 98px;
  height: 48px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<form id="myform">

</form>
```